# For grid search using H2O in Python, where should we set the seed?

Tags: python, h2o

I saw there are a few places that we can set up seed when we do grid search for tuning hyper parameters, for example, we can set up seed in the following 3 places

1. when we initialize the estimator using H2OGradientBoostingEstimator,
2. when we define the search_criteria, we can also put seed
3. when we start to use the defined grid to train, we can also put seed in the train function

Are these 3 redundant, we only need set up in one of them or each of them play different role?

thanks!

Comment: I think each play different role. Seed in the estimator is related to algorithm component itself, nothing to do with tuning hyperparameters. While seed in grid search determines how h2o will search randomly in all possible value combination of hyperparameters.

Comment: that make sense. How about the seed in train statement?

Comment: you might be more specific. but it can be for randomly splitting data train-test

Comment: where are you seeing a seed parameter for the grid train method: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html?#h2o.grid.grid_search.H2OGridSearch.train ? @bakka you pretty much have the answer, it would be great if you could post your comment as an answer. For full grid search see explanations see the docs http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places where you can specify a seed when using the Python API

1) The Estimator, let's take GBM as the example

```
gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds=5, seed=1234)
gbm.train(x=features,y=response,training_frame=train)
```

Notice how I don't specify a seed within the `train` method. If you pass a seed argument to `train` it will break.

From the API [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.estimator_base.H2OEstimator.train) you can see that no seed argument is provided.

`train(x=None, y=None, training_frame=None, offset_column=None, fold_column=None, weights_column=None, validation_frame=None, max_runtime_secs=None, ignored_columns=None, model_id=None, verbose=False)`

From the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/seed.html) here is the definition for an Estimator's seed.

*This option specifies the random number generator (RNG) seed for algorithms that are dependent on randomization. When a seed is defined, the algorithm will behave deterministically.
The seed is consistent for each H2O instance so that you can create models with the same starting conditions in alternative configurations.*

2) the `search_criteria` in [H2OGridSearch](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2ogridsearch). For the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html):

*More about search_criteria:
This is a dictionary of control parameters for smarter hyperparameter search. The dictionary can include values for: strategy, max_models, max_runtime_secs, stopping_metric, stopping_tolerance, stopping_rounds and seed. The default value for strategy, “Cartesian”, covers the entire space of hyperparameter combinations. If you want to use cartesian grid search, you can leave the search_criteria argument unspecified. Specify the “RandomDiscrete” strategy to perform a random search of all the combinations of your hyperparameters. RandomDiscrete should be usually combined with at least one early stopping criterion, max_models and/or max_runtime_secs. Some examples below:*

While you can pass in a seed parameter to the `train` method for grid search without having anything break, the seed parameter there does nothing. If you want to have reproducible grid search runs you need to specify the seed argument in the search_criteria parameter like so

```
# build grid search with previously made GBM and hyper parameters
grid = H2OGridSearch(model = my_model, hyper_params = hyper_params,
                     search_criteria = {'strategy': "RandomDiscrete", "max_runtime_secs" : 10, "seed" :1234})

# train using the grid
grid.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)
```

Comment: Lauren, thanks for your explanation. You mentioned train cannot have seed. But does the train in grid search can have seed? Is that the same as you put in estimator? I found the example from the following link: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html

Comment: hi @Gavin yes train for the estimator does not have a seed and if you pass a seed it should throw an error, but grid search is different and when you apply train because it accepts extra arguments it will allow you to pass in a seed parameter even if it doesn't use it. I realize this can be confusing so my recommendation is just use the seed parameter when you instantiate your estimator and in stopping_criteria for grid search.